# Constructor inheritance behaving weirdly

Tags: c++, constructor

In the following situation:

```
class A 
{
  protected:
    int m_int;
    A() : m_int{-2} {};

  public:
    A(const A& a) { m_int = a.get(); }
    A& operator=(const A& a) { m_int = a.get(); return *this; }
    int get() const { return m_int; }
};

class B : public A
{
  protected:
    using A::m_int;

  public:
    // same constructors as parent, but public
    using A::A;
};

class C : public B
{
  public:
    // same constructors as parent
    using B::B;
    C(int x) { m_int = x; }
    C(const B& b) { C(b.get()); }
};

class D : public C
{
  public:
    // same constructors as parent
    using C::C;
    D(const B& b) { D(b.get()); }
};

int main()
{
  C c(5);
  D d(c);

  return d.get();
}
```

1. I would expect for `main()` to return `5`. Instead, it returns `-2`. It seems it's calling the default constructor of `A`, whereas I would have expected for it to call the `D(const B& b)` constructor. What's going on?
2. Why do I need to provide an explicit constructor for `C(const B& b)`? I would have guessed for a default behavior to be deduced, for inheritance reasons. What am I missing?

Comment: The explicit constructor for `C(const B& b)` is necessary because it's not a copy-constructor: in general it's not guaranteed that a `B` object will have all of the data necessary to construct a `C` object.  For example, when you add any member-variables to `C` that need to be initialized, there would be no way to initialize them from their counterparts in a `B` since the `B` class doesn't contain those member-variables.  (I suppose the compiler could default-initialize them in that case, but that would likely lead to unexpected run-time behavior that is better dealt with at compile-time)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the constructor in `D`:

```
D(const B& b) { D(b.get()); }
```

This will be the constructor that is called. And it doesn't copy the value from `b`, instead it creates a new and ***temporary*** `D` object which is promptly destructed as the constructor function exit.

You have the same problem in the corresponding `C` constructor:

```
C(const B& b) { C(b.get()); }
```

You should use a constructor initializer list to delegate to the correct constructor:

```
D(const B& b) : C(b.get()) {}
```

Comment: Thanks, this clarifies point 1 entirely. I'm still a bit confuse about why there's no inherited constructor for the case in point 2 (although I get why the explicit one in my example is not the correct one).

Comment: Because the implicitly generated constructor for `C` will accept an argument of type `const C &`, not of type `const B &`.    You're forcing the class to accept construction of a `C` using a `B`, which is not a copy constructor.